# When using netcat to process logs in spark streaming, it is dropping last few lines?

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming, netcat

I have a spark-streaming service, where I am processing and detecting anomalies on the basis of some offline generated model. I feed data into this service from a log file, which is streamed using the following command

```
tail -f <logfile>| nc -lk 9999
```

Here the spark streaming service is taking data from port 9999. However, I observe that the last few lines are being dropped, i.e. spark streaming does not receive those log lines or they are not processed.

However, I also observed that if I simply take the logfile as standard input instead of tailing it, no lines are dropped:

```
nc -q 10 -lk 9999 < logfile
```

Can anyone explain why this behavior is happening? And what could be a better resolution to the problem of streaming log data to spark streaming instance?

Comment: I have used the same but haven't experienced any problem. Though the right Architecture would be use some reailable mechanism for capturing Logs for example Flume or Apache Nifi would be a better choice for capturing Streaming Data and then submitting it to Spark Streaming job . Fume integrates pretty well with Spark Streaming. See [here](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-flume-integration.html)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I'd like to figure out the behavior here as well. Did you use tail -f <logfile>|nc -lk 9999 option in your setting, it seems to work for streaming, but when I am doing archived log replay.. it often fails to process the very last log, or the last couple of logs?

Comment: I used `tail -f <logfile>` for fetching new logs generated by a web application. Did not tried with replaying archived logs, though logically I do not see any difference.

Answer (score 0):

In [Spark Streaming](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-programming-guide.html), data comes in over the wire, and constitutes a *block* on every *block interval*. This block is replicated on other machines (according to your [storage level](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/programming-guide.html) as soon as formed. Once a *batch interval* elapses, each block formed since the last batch interval tick forms part of a new `RDD`. It is once you have formed this `RDD` that you can schedule a job, so the data *collected* during the batch interval `n` is then *processed* during batch interval `n+1`.

So, the possible culprits for "losing a bit of data towards the end" could be:

- you are observing your input file at the same time as you are monitoring the input for Spark. If you consider your monitoring at instant `t`, a bit after `n` batch intervals have elapsed, your log file has produced the data for `n` batches and then some ("a little bit more"). Except, the beginning of the next batch (`n+1`) is at this stage in the data collection phase, in the form of blocks on your Receiver. No data has been lost, the processing of batch `n+1` has simply not started yet.
- or your application assumes it's receiving a similar number of elements in each `RDD` and does not process the potentially (much) smaller *last* batch's `RDD` correctly.
- or you're stopping your application or data before the last batch interval elapses (you need to wait `n+1` batch intervals to see the processing of `n` batches of data).
- or there is something weird occurring with the system clock of your executors. Have you thought of synchronizing them with [ntp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_Time_Protocol) ?